# Python ImportError for installed packages

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scipy, python-import

Installing numpy says that it is already the newest version, and it shows up in the list returned by `pip list` too, but importing it gives import error (and this problem is there for every other installed module e.g. scipy, matplotlib).

**What is wrong with the system and how to resolve this?**

```
sunny@sunny:~$ pip list
adium-theme-ubuntu (0.3.4)
cycler (0.9.0)
decorator (4.0.6)
matplotlib (1.5.1)
numpy (1.11.0)
Pillow (3.1.2)
pip (8.1.1)
pyeemd (1.3.1)
pyparsing (2.0.3)
python-dateutil (2.4.2)
pytz (2014.10)
scipy (0.17.0)
setuptools (20.7.0)
six (1.10.0)
unity-lens-photos (1.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
sunny@sunny:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, May 28 2016, 17:16:00) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>> quit()
sunny@sunny:~$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-numpy is already the newest version (1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
sunny@sunny:~$
```

**EDIT:** I tried to use pip3 for python3 on my Ubuntu system to get imports working (I had never touched python3 before), and I again get the same old result as above, which is

```
sunny@sunny:~$ pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.11.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (15.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 15.6MB 57kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
sunny@sunny:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, May 28 2016, 17:16:00) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>> quit()
sunny@sunny:~$ pip3 list
apturl (0.5.2)
beautifulsoup4 (4.4.1)
blinker (1.3)
Brlapi (0.6.4)
chardet (2.3.0)
checkbox-support (0.22)
command-not-found (0.3)
cryptography (1.2.3)
defer (1.0.6)
feedparser (5.1.3)
guacamole (0.9.2)
html5lib (0.999)
httplib2 (0.9.1)
idna (2.0)
Jinja2 (2.8)
language-selector (0.1)
louis (2.6.4)
lxml (3.5.0)
Mako (1.0.3)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
numpy (1.11.1)
oauthlib (1.0.3)
onboard (1.2.0)
padme (1.1.1)
pexpect (4.0.1)
Pillow (3.1.2)
pip (8.1.1)
plainbox (0.25)
ptyprocess (0.5)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycups (1.9.73)
pycurl (7.43.0)
pygobject (3.20.0)
PyJWT (1.3.0)
pyparsing (2.0.3)
python-apt (1.1.0b1)
python-debian (0.1.27)
python-systemd (231)
pyxdg (0.25)
reportlab (3.3.0)
requests (2.9.1)
sessioninstaller (0.0.0)
setuptools (20.7.0)
six (1.10.0)
system-service (0.3)
ubuntu-drivers-common (0.0.0)
ufw (0.35)
unattended-upgrades (0.1)
unity-scope-calculator (0.1)
unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks (0.1)
unity-scope-colourlovers (0.1)
unity-scope-devhelp (0.1)
unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks (0.1)
unity-scope-gdrive (0.7)
unity-scope-manpages (0.1)
unity-scope-openclipart (0.1)
unity-scope-texdoc (0.1)
unity-scope-tomboy (0.1)
unity-scope-virtualbox (0.1)
unity-scope-yelp (0.1)
unity-scope-zotero (0.1)
urllib3 (1.13.1)
usb-creator (0.3.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
xdiagnose (3.8.4)
xkit (0.0.0)
XlsxWriter (0.7.3)
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
sunny@sunny:~$
```

Comment: The packages are not necessarily imported with the same name you used to install them. But this isn't the case for numpy, so you may add the tag `numpy` to your question. Try to run `sudo apt-get remove python-numpy`, and install it with pip. (`pip install numpy`)

Comment: @CodingLambdas Actually, pip install throws this weird error on my system "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'" which I had asked help for some days ago, but couldn't get any!

Comment: Your installation of pip seems to be damaged a lot... Did you try to reinstall pip? And if this doesn't work, did you try to reinstall python? Another possible problem: Are you using pip of python2 and run python3 or the other way around?

Comment: I have tried reinstalling both of them, and am currently trying this again (will report the result, if it works). I guess I am sure of that! Do you suggest any checks?

Comment: I don't know any other problems that could cause that. (The last problem with py2 and py3 is a problem, that I had in a slightly different setup because I needed miniconda for a project, and miniconda installs a whole separate installation of python for some reason.)

Comment: Are you using an official python build? Or something special?

Comment: I started with pre-installed python on ubuntu, and have had reinstalled it with sudo apt-get install --reinstall python2.7

Comment: @CodingLambdas I have tried pip3 for python3, and have included the results in the edited section, you might want to give it a look!

Comment: @mirror I would like to fully understand what you have tried so far. Can you try `readlink -f $(which python)` in the terminal? Also, now that you have installed `python-numpy` via `apt-get`, can you try running `python` in the terminal and then import `numpy` and see what happens?

Comment: I would check permissions on the numpy you have installed and whether it's where you expect it to be. Also, are you by any chance behind a proxy (school, work, ...)? As a last resort I would compile python. As @CodingLambdas said, your env seems to be damaged. I would start fresh.

Answer (score 1):

You installed numpy for python3.5.*, but you import it in python2.7.11. Isn't it?

```
sunny@sunny:~$ pip3 install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.11.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (15.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 15.6MB 57kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy
```

"cp35" in the name "numpy-1.11.1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl" mean it's for python3.5.* .

```
sunny@sunny:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, May 28 2016, 17:16:00) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

but here, you enter "python", then open python2.7.11 not python3.5.* .
so try "cd" to the installation directory of python3.5.*, then enter "python3.5.exe".
wish help you.